# Returning deleted records in gorm

Tags: go-gorm

Can you please help the with the correct usage of clause.Returning{}.

Visual studio throws "undefined: clause compiler(UndeclaredName)" error for the below statement.

db.Clauses(clause.Returning{}).Limit()

I tried many combination such as gorm.clause.Returning{}.

Please guide me how to add Returning struct in Clauses.

Comment: Hi,  It is resolved by import  "gorm.io/gorm/clause"